# Render is Blank (Empty)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm working on this donut for my first time on Blender, and I opened a vertical split. But I can't see the original object or image. Also when I try to render the image, it says "Launch failed". Here is a screenshot:

As you can see on the left, it's not showing the rendered image. Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated. :)

[image: As you can see on the left, it's not showing the rendered image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts.

Answer (score 2):

Under Render Properties > Device **switch from GPU to CPU**. Your graphics card can't handle this task.

Comment: Oh okay! thanks buddy!

Comment: If it answered your Q, consider mark A as Solved (checkmark under vote number) so others can see it from a list.